# Cypher: how to use a regex in shortcut match expression?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Beginner Cypher query. I know how to use a regex in a MATCH expression:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*'
RETURN p;
```

And I also know the more compact form for MATCH expressions without regexes:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:"Rebecca"})
RETURN p;
```

But is there any way I can use the regex in the more compact form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Inline queries are only aware of an `EQUALS` operator.

So

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:"Rebecca"})
```

is always translated to `name` EQUALS `Rebecca`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!